# how do i place a div below another div?

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to place a notification box below a sign up form, but it keeps staying above it.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: .1em 0;
  color: #444;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
h1:before {
  left: -.5em;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50%;
}
h1:after {
  left: .5em;
  margin: 0 -50% 0 0;
}
h1 > span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: normal;
}
p {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
/** notifications **/

.notify {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 2px 0px;
}
.notify h1 {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.successbox h1 {
  color: #678361;
}
.errorbox h1 {
  color: #6f423b;
}
.successbox h1:before,
.successbox h1:after {
  background: #cad8a9;
}
.errorbox h1:before,
.errorbox h1:after {
  background: #d6b8b7;
}
.notify .alerticon {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cd-user-modal">
  <!-- content-->
</div>
<div class="notify errorbox">
  <h1>Warning!</h1>
  <span class="alerticon"><img src="images/error.png" alt="error" /></span>
  <p>You did not set the proper return e-mail address. Please fill out the fields and then submit the form.</p>
</div>
```

I tried changing the padding and margin but it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

This is basically a box that fades away when u click on it, i did not include the javascript code in it.

Playing with the position (changing it from relative to absolute and so on) did not yield to a solution.. Im not really sure how to use them

Thank you!

Comment: can you please give jsfiddle link?

Comment: Seems fine in your snippet.

Comment: Is the div with the `cd-user-modal` your div that contains the sign-up form? If so, your snippet seems to work fine, so I am not seeing the issue here.

Comment: @SpencerDoak yes, but it isnt working

Answer (score 1):

use `visibility:hidden;`  and  `visibility: visible;` for `div.notify.errorbox`

[CSS visibility Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)

```js
$('.show').click(function(){
  $('.errorbox').css('visibility','visible')
  })

$('.hide').click(function(){
  $('.errorbox').css('visibility','hidden')
  })
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: .1em 0;
  color: #444;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
h1:before {
  left: -.5em;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50%;
}
h1:after {
  left: .5em;
  margin: 0 -50% 0 0;
}
h1 > span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: normal;
}
p {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
/** notifications **/

.notify {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 2px 0px;
}
.notify h1 {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.successbox h1 {
  color: #678361;
}
.errorbox h1 {
  color: #6f423b;
}
.successbox h1:before,
.successbox h1:after {
  background: #cad8a9;
}
.errorbox h1:before,
.errorbox h1:after {
  background: #d6b8b7;
}
.notify .alerticon {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.errorbox{visibility:hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cd-user-modal">
   content here
  <button class="show">show errorbox</button>
  <button class="hide">hide errorbox</button>
</div>

<div class="notify errorbox">
  <h1>Warning!</h1>
  <span class="alerticon"><img src="images/error.png" alt="error" /></span>
  <p>You did not set the proper return e-mail address. Please fill out the fields and then submit the form.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this was not really my question. my question was, how can i make the  notify div appear under the cd-user-modal div. both are already there i just want to position them